# Stream Analytics - No such host is known

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

We are in Australia East.

We have an event hub with events coming through from an application.  On Friday 19th March morning I created a Stream Analytics job, to try and read one of the event streams.  This worked successfully on the Event Hub and returned results in the "Input preview" window when setting this up. This seems to match the timings on the message below (we are about 12 hours in front of UTC).

However by Friday afternoon, it started failing with one of the error messages "InternalServerError" or "No such host is known".  I was working through the drop down boxes available when creating a new input after selecting "Select Event Hub from your subscriptions", so I know I haven't got anything wrong in the setup.

When trying to submit a support request, we get this slightly cryptic message:
[image: Trying to submit support request]

The link doesn't work, it claims Stream Analytics is not supported in Resource Health, even though it is. Does this mean "It's down sorry, we are working on it" (as in actually working on it), or is it a canned response and we should escalate it?

Or is anyone else having trouble creating Stream Analytics Jobs and we are suffering an outage? The Azure Status monitor shows they are in good health.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was a permission error.  I needed to go into the IAM of the Event Hub and set the Stream Analytics Job up with Reader permissions. For some reason, this wasn't automatically added when setting up the Stream Analytics Job, as I thought it would be.

Once the permission was set, the job started successfully.

Comment: Something weird must have been happening with the permissions when I first did this. I started another stream analytics job a few days later and the reader permission for it was added automatically.